# How to replace slices of a certain length with an array of same length while iterating over its parent vector

Tags: rust, slice

I am trying to replace all the slices of length 8 iff they match with a particular `[_; 8]` (`source_steam_id`), with the contents of another array (`target_steam_id`) with the same size. I am using [`windows(8)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) to iterate over its parent collection but it seems like the compiler is not understanding I am trying to take 8 items at a time and that the size is known at compile time.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Character {
    save_data: Vec<u8>,
}

fn main() {
    // setup
    let source_character = Character {
        save_data: vec![3, 27, 22, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 99, 27],
    };

    // Replace steam id in the result Character
    // with the steam id of the target Character
    // in the target Character save_data
    let mut result_character = source_character.clone();
    let source_steam_id: [u8; 8] = [1; 8];
    let target_steam_id: [u8; 8] = [2; 8];
    result_character.save_data = result_character
        .save_data
        .windows(8) // id is an [u8; 8]
        .map(|w| {
            if w[..] == source_steam_id[..] {
                target_steam_id[..]
            } else {
                w[..]
            }
        })
        .collect();
    dbg!(&result_character.save_data);
}
```

The compiler [says](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f48236be74509a94eee206eaf989ca85)

> the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`

at `map(|w|`. How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be avoided by simply taking a reference, or by using `as_slice`:

```rust
&w[..] == source_steam_id.as_slice()
```

but mapping over windows will not let you reconstruct the whole `Vec` in the end.
Instead assuming you only want to replace one occurence, you can find it using `position` and use `copy_from_slice`:

```rust
    const ID_NUM_BYTES: usize = 8;
    let pos = result_character
        .save_data
        .windows(ID_NUM_BYTES)
        .position(|w| &w[..] == source_steam_id.as_slice()).unwrap();
    result_character.save_data[pos..pos+8].copy_from_slice(&target_steam_id);
```

This has the added benefit that only the changed 8 bytes have to be written, not the whole vector.

---

If it does appear multiple times you can use `enumerate` and `filter_map` to find all occurences first and then replace the same way:

```rust
    let positions = result_character
        .save_data
        .windows(ID_NUM_BYTES)
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(i, w)| (&w[..] == source_steam_id.as_slice()).then_some(i))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    for pos in positions {
        result_character.save_data[pos..pos+8].copy_from_slice(&target_steam_id);
    }
```

---

Of course that last solution suffers from the problem that you replace all overlapping matches, which might or might not be what you want (as Jmb ninjad while I was thinking about how to solve it).
If you don't want it I'd use `lending_iterator`s `windows_mut` rather than checking each new pos is > `ID_NUM_BYTES` after the last one:

```rust
use ::lending_iterator::prelude::*;
    // …
    result_character
        .save_data
        .windows_mut::<ID_NUM_BYTES>()
        .for_each(|w| {
            if w as &[u8] == source_steam_id {
                w.copy_from_slice(&target_steam_id)
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be multiple occurrences of ID that need to be replaced.  Is there any useful function that will return an iterator of positions?

Comment: Note that the "multiple times" solution may or may not do what you want if there are overlapping IDs, e.g. given `ID="12341234"`, `data="x123412341234y"` and `target="ABCDEFGH"`, you will get `"xABCDABCDEFGHy"`.